# rearranging of XML elements and extracting relevant data from its values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i want to rearrange  XML elements and extract relevant values from each element to produce an XML or cvs output.

I read in some materials that (xsl:value-of) is used in extracting values of element but I’m not sure how it can be used to extract specific values from an element.
these is a sample XML data,

```
<Add>
<Row>
<L>1</L>
<LD>Dwelling  (Part Of), Null</LD>
<th>NULL</th>
<AA>Abesinia Passage</AA>
<LN>Dwelling  (Part Of)</LN>
</Row>
```

for example, i want to extract any value whcih has  Estate or island  as suffix from the (Addressarea) element.

i also want to remove any NULL value or value with the suffix Estate or island from the (thoroughfare) element.

Comment: lee, I think you need to ask new questions for the last two here -- please provide the source XML and the exact wanted result. The data and result to be provided need be short.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pOrder" select=
  "'|LocatorDesignator|LocatorName|Locator|thoroughfare|addressArea|'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOrder" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pOrder']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Rowinfo">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
     <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
     "string-length(substring-before($pOrder, concat('|', name(), '|')))"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (produced by the answer of your previous question):

```
<Address>
   <Rowinfo>
      <Locator>1</Locator>
      <LocatorDesignator>Null, Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
      <thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
      <LocatorName>Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorName>
      <addressArea>Some Address Area</addressArea>
   </Rowinfo>
   <Rowinfo>
      <Locator>1a</Locator>
      <LocatorDesignator>Null, Edmund's Home</LocatorDesignator>
      <thoroughfare>Arena's Palace Lane</thoroughfare>
      <LocatorName>Edmund's Home</LocatorName>
      <addressArea>Some Other Address Area</addressArea>
   </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Address>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Null, Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Dwelling  (Part Of)</LocatorName>
        <Locator>1</Locator>
        <thoroughfare>Abesinia Passage</thoroughfare>
        <addressArea>Some Address Area</addressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Null, Edmund's Home</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Edmund's Home</LocatorName>
        <Locator>1a</Locator>
        <thoroughfare>Arena's Palace Lane</thoroughfare>
        <addressArea>Some Other Address Area</addressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

Comment: thank you Dimitre thats a better approach..am hoping you could look through the second question aswell.

Comment: @lee: replacing/deleting substrings in text nodes is a question that has been asked many times at SO and has many good answers -- just search or you may ask a new question/

Comment: @lee, SO is "Stack Overflow". As for not producing the wanted result, it is possible the names as entered in the parameter in this solution aren't exactly (includinge capitalization) the same as in your XML documrnt. I'll verify this.

Comment: @lee, Yes, in the param "AddressArea` is spelled "addressArea". Just correct and the transformation does what you want.

Comment: @lee, I am at work right now -- can have a look at this in 8-10 hrs. from now.